# What brush engine is exquisite forest. built upon?

Tags: javascript, wacom

http://www.exquisiteforest.com has an awesome paint application written in pure javascript, does anyone know what JavaScript brush engine is used for the creating it (with pen pressure support)

Comment: http://www.exquisiteforest.com/about/technology

Comment: I'm guessing you need the Wacom plugin: http://www.wacom.com/CustomerCare/Plugin.aspx

Comment: I'm looking for the JS framework that calculate and render the brush strokes using the input from the wacom tablet.

Comment: I'm assuming it's homebrewed by them.

Comment: @StephenDocy instead of editing typos in years-old unanswered question and pushing them onto the main page again, please just vote to close it as the off-topic question that it is (now).